# Python Pandas Add Value to Multiple Rows Based on Date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I need to solve a data science problem using only **Python** and **Pandas** where the given input is the date of check in, the date of check out, and the payments of every books from a single person

```
check_in   check_out  payment
2020-02-28 2020-03-02 66
2020-02-27 2020-02-29 100
```

I need to show how much daily earnings I got from that 2 books earlier. I got the idea that I have to split it for each date like 66/3 and distribute it from 02-28 to 03-02 and 100/2 then distribute it from 02-27 to 02-29 for the second order, then I will get result like this

```
date       earnings
2020-02-27 50
2020-02-28 22+50
2020-02-29 22
2020-03-01 22
```

Which will be like this if I summed them up

```
date       earnings
2020-02-27 50
2020-02-28 72
2020-02-29 22
2020-03-01 22
```

I have already divided the payment column from input and create a new dataframe with two new columns which represent how long did the guests stay using **day_stay** and how much earnings did I receive with **daily_earn** using the code below

```
df["date_stay"] = abs(df["check_in"] - df["check_out"]) # Get difference
df["date_stay"] = pd.to_numeric(df["date_stay"].dt.days) # Turn to days
df["daily_earn"] = df["payment"]/df["date_stay"]
```

Then the result will be look like this

```
check_in   check_out  payment day_stay daily_earn
2020-02-28 2020-03-02 66      3        22
2020-02-27 2020-02-29 100     2        50
```

The last step is to distribute the value in **daily_earn** to the corresponding date from 02-27 to 03-01 but I don't have any idea to do that. I have tried to use **df.groupby("check_in").sum()** but it didn't give the desired output since the number of rows between the input and output is different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try a different approach:

```
df['date'] = df.apply(
    lambda r: pd.date_range(r['check_in'], r['check_out'], closed='left'),
    axis=1)

df = df.explode('date')

df['earnings'] = df['payment'] / df.groupby(level=0)['date'].transform('count')

df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['earnings'].agg('sum')
```

`df`:

```
        date  earnings
0 2020-02-27      50.0
1 2020-02-28      72.0
2 2020-02-29      22.0
3 2020-03-01      22.0
```

---

Breakdown of steps:

[`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to each row to get the days between start and end:

```
df['date'] = df.apply(
    lambda r: pd.date_range(r['check_in'], r['check_out'], closed='left'),
    axis=1)
```

```
    check_in  check_out  payment                                                                                         date
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66  DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
1 2020-02-27 2020-02-29      100                DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-27', '2020-02-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the `date` into rows:

```
df = df.explode('date')
```

```
    check_in  check_out  payment       date
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-02-28
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-02-29
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-03-01
1 2020-02-27 2020-02-29      100 2020-02-27
1 2020-02-27 2020-02-29      100 2020-02-28
```

Then [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) count `date` to get the number of dates and divide the payment by the number of days to get the daily earnings:

```
df['earnings'] = df['payment'] / df.groupby(level=0)['date'].transform('count')
```

```
    check_in  check_out  payment       date  earnings
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-02-28      22.0
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-02-29      22.0
0 2020-02-28 2020-03-02       66 2020-03-01      22.0
1 2020-02-27 2020-02-29      100 2020-02-27      50.0
1 2020-02-27 2020-02-29      100 2020-02-28      50.0
```

Then [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) sum the earnings on the `date` to get the total per `date`:

```
df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['earnings'].agg('sum')
```

```
        date  earnings
0 2020-02-27      50.0
1 2020-02-28      72.0
2 2020-02-29      22.0
3 2020-03-01      22.0
```

---

DataFrame and imports used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'check_in': {0: '2020-02-28', 1: '2020-02-27'},
                   'check_out': {0: '2020-03-02', 1: '2020-02-29'},
                   'payment': {0: 66, 1: 100}})
df['check_in'] = pd.to_datetime(df['check_in'])
df['check_out'] = pd.to_datetime(df['check_out'])
```